# 30N06L N-channel mosfet switching heavy load interfering with micro-controller circuit

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, mosfet-driver

I have a microcontroller that I want to use to switch on/off a heavy load (a car horn) with a [30N06L N-channel mosfet](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/General/FQP30N06L.pdf). Everything works when running a load of 4Kohms (with the car battery at 12v), but when I move to the heavy load of the horn, then things go awry. I can hear an initial honk, but then the horn stops. I am guessing that the high current powering the horn is causing interference with the rest of the circuit somehow. Does anyone have experience with this?

Also, the reason I am going with this particular mosfet is because it is what I had laying around. If it makes more sense to go to a similar P-Channel mosfet, I can order a few.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f14p5C.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: There's a button in the editor that looks like a circuit diagram with a pencil on it. Try clicking that to draw a better circuit diagram. The one you have might be good enough, though, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

Your testing suggests that the larger current of the horn is causing problems - perhaps involving the microcontroller. The circuit might benefit by adding a flyback diode across the horn (cathode to +12V).

Since MOSfet source pin is common with microcontroller ground pin, some grounding problems can occur here:[image: modified (crude) schematic]

Comment: +1 - all the main issues nailed down.

Comment: So how do I isolate the source pin from the rest of the ground?

Comment: that blue wire,

Comment: Adding the diode doesn't seem to change anything. Also, all the grounds are already connected.

Comment: @ChaseRoberts Green wire carries relatively small currents, and is involved with turning the MOSfet's gate ON/OFF. It is probably best that its route to battery "-" be *only* via the MOSfet source. Green should carry no horn current. Blue carries large horn current plus the smaller green current. Connecting the voltage regulator end of green directly to battery "-" can cause problems. I would try to keep the length of green short and direct.